# How to comment a tag using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to comment this tag using sed command, but I always get a "bad substitution" error.

Here is the tag:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="${jboss.web.http.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
         redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}" />
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: my out put should be like this :

Comment: <!-- comment Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="${jboss.web.http.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
         redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}" /-->

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/Connector protocol/{s/</&!--/;n;s/>$/--&/}' log
```

You can chage `/Connector protocol/` with whatever identifier you wish to comment on.